# Remove string from a vector

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to remove a string from a vector this way:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *x*(vector 1 "ab" 3))
*X*                                   
CL-USER> (remove "ab" *x*)
#(1 "ab" 3)
```

I want to obtain `#(1 3)` as a result of the last operation.

Can anyone explain me what is going on how do I obtain the intended result?

I'm using SBCL + Slime + Emacs + Ubuntu 14.04.

**EDIT**:

I think I found the answer, is because the default comparison function is EQL, while a string comparison should be performed with string= function.

One problem remains, because you can not use string= for numbers. Maybe with a new function to compare each variable depending on it's type can be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *One problem remains, because you can not use string= for numbers. Maybe with a new function to compare each variable depending on it's
>   type can be solved.*

First, note that you're not comparing *variables*, you're comparing *values*.  Function arguments are evaluated *before* the function is called.  You can do **(string= (aref some-strings 3) (make-string …))** and compare two strings, but neither (as far as we know) is the value of a variable.  I stress this only because you can't compare a *variable* based on its type in Common Lisp, because variables don't have types;  *values* have types.

Anyhow, that was an aside;  Common Lisp includes functions that do what you're looking for.  You can use [**equal**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm#equal) or [**equalp**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equalp.htm#equalp), which will descend into the string, but won't complain about comparing different types of objects:

```
CL-USER> (remove "ab" #(1 "ab" 3))
#(1 "ab" 3)
CL-USER> (remove "ab" #(1 "ab" 3) :test 'equal)
#(1 3)
CL-USER> (remove "ab" #(1 "ab" 3) :test 'equalp)
#(1 3)
```

**Equalp** will compare case insensitively:

```
CL-USER> (remove "aB" #(1 "ab" 3) :test 'equal)
#(1 "ab" 3)
CL-USER> (remove "aB" #(1 "ab" 3) :test 'equalp)
#(1 3)
```